# How to set up CodeIgniter controllers for similar forms in different directories

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter to access a variety of form types

I have a directory such as this:

```
-views
--resources
---app1
----form.php
---app2
----form.php
---app3
----form.php
---app4
----form.php
```

My class is currently very basic, but this

```
class Resources extends CI_Controller {

        public function app1($page = '')
        {
                $data['title'] = ucfirst($folder); // Capitalize the first letter

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('resources/app1/form.php', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);


        }

        public function app2($page = '')
        {
                $data['title'] = ucfirst($folder); // Capitalize the first letter

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('resources/app2/form.php', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);


        }

}
```

This seems very verbose and unnecessary to have a method for every form. However I can't find how I can change the directory without creating a new method. I would ideally like a method where I can pass in a new directory as an arg like $page can be. Eg:

```
class Resources extends CI_Controller {

        public function view($page = '')
        {
                $data['title'] = ucfirst($folder); // Capitalize the first letter

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('resources/'. $folder. '/form.php', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);


        }

}
```

However, it seems CodeIgniter doesn't allow this. Can anyone suggest a way in which this can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can.

Create a `base_controller` inside your `core` folder and call it `MY_Controller.php` and make it extends `CI_Controller` and create a method inside `MY_Controller` and name it `render, render_view, view` whatever you want and inside that function load you layout partials and template and just pass the view to it: `application/core/MY_Controller.php`

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    protected $data = array();

    public function render_view($view = '')
    {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $this->data);
            $this->load->view('view_path/'. $view, $this->data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $this->data);
    }
}
```

and for every controller in your application make it extend `MY_Controller` and whenever you wanna render a view use `render_view($view)` and you got you `header` and `footer` preloaded, and that's the simplest way of making it DRY.

Finally in your controller it should be like this:

```
class Resources extends CI_Controller {

    public function app1($page = '')
    {
            // $data array in my_controller, it will automatically be passed inside render_view
            $this->data['title'] = ucfirst($folder); // Capitalize the first letter
            $this->render_view('app1/form');
    }

    public function app2($page = '')
    {
            $this->data['title'] = ucfirst($folder); // Capitalize the first letter
            $this->render_view('app2/form');
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm going to use this so I don't have to load header and footer in every method. However, I'm looking for a way to load all the forms using one method. If I use a method per form, my methods could be unlimited (well into the hundreds) and that seems unnecessary when I just need to change the directory of the form in the method when loading the view.

Comment: You can achieve that here, i'm doing that myself .. i don't even have to use render_view unless i'm changing the template, but it takes a lot more code inside base controller to achieve that but i'll give you a hint, you can render the view based on the `controller name represents view dir name` and `method name represents view or form name`

Answer (score 0):

Calling your function "view" is almost certainly a bad idea...  it's used by CI for the $this->load->view() for starters.

```
    public function app_form($page = '')
    {
        $data['title'] = ucfirst($folder); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('resources/'. $page. '/form.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    }
```

That should work but how are you going to call the functions?  Via the routes.php file?

Comment: That's an oversight. I just wrote that as an example of a method I'm looking to have - I wouldn't call in view in my app.